# Creating image from canvas results in blank image in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**Okay I found out what the problem was. Every time you say new Image() you HAVE to use the onload handler to ensure that the image has really load. Even if you assign the src attr via toDataURL.**

I want to get a subimage of a given image.
In Google Chrome when I type `console.log(createSubImg(img, 0, 0, 20, 20));`
I can see the image. In Firefox I see an empty image.
What did I wrong?

My method looks like:

```
function createSubImg(img, x, y, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(
            img,
            x * width,
            y * height,
            width,
            height,
            0,
            0,
            width,
            height);


    var result = new Image();
    result.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: hi, what is in the `img` variable?

Comment: Hello. It is an html image element.

Comment: edited my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

It works for me like this:

```
var img;
(function(){
    img = document.getElementById('example');
    img.onload = function(){
         console.log(createSubImg(img, 0, 0, 20, 20));
    };
});
```

and if I write `console.log(createSubImg(img, 0, 0, 20, 20));` in Firefox it works too.

Answer (score 0):

Here Is The Solution

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="position: relative;">
    <img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="Images/01.jpg" alt="The Scream" />

    <img id="test" src="#" />
</form>
```

Script part is here

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var img = document.getElementById("scream");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var res = createSubImg(img, 0, 0, 200, 200, canvas, ctx);
        var myImage = $("#test");
        myImage.attr('src', res.src);
    });

    function createSubImg(img, x, y, width, height, canvas, ctx) {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx.drawImage(
                    img,
                    x * width,
                    y * height,
                    width,
                    height,
                    0,
                    0,
                    width,
                    height);

        var result = new Image();
        result.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        return result;
    }
</script>
```